# How to combine html checkbox form with table td tr and href link

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I need some help about how to combine these two html codes, to make table based checkbox forms. Code2 display a mysql query result. I don't know where to put the table tr and td codes to be able to work correctly.

Code1:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');   
echo "<!DOCTYPE HTML>";
echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";
echo '<form action="testing.php" method="post">';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="dtest" value="row0fromsqlresult">aaa<br>';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="dtest" value="row1fromsqlresult">bbb<br>';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="dtest" value="row2fromsqlresult">ccc<br>';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="dtest" value="row3fromsqlresult">ddd<br>';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="dtest" value="row4fromsqlresult">eee<br>';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="dtest" value="row5fromsqlresult">fff<br>';
echo '<button type="submit">Submit</button>';
echo '</form>';
echo '</body>';
echo '</html>';
?>
```

with this:

Code2:

```
<?php
echo "<table width='90%' border='1'>";
while ( false!=($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlresult)) ) {
echo '
    <tr>
        <td><a href="getdetail.php?id=', urlencode($row['row0']), '">',
            htmlspecialchars($row['row1']),
        '</td>
        <td>', htmlspecialchars($row['row2']), '</td>
        <td>', htmlspecialchars($row['row3']), '</td>            
        <td>', htmlspecialchars($row['row4']), '</td>       
        <td>', htmlspecialchars($row['row5']), '</td>                 
    </tr>
';
}


echo '</table>';

?>
```

What I would like is an checkbox infront of each sql result line.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have more than one problem here.   Do you just want your form to appear with the checkboxes? Or are you also needing assistance with submitting the results (e.g. making sure that the rows are unique).  Also you are using deprecate php code, which means it will soon stop working, and any submissions with this will be vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Dear nomistic, i would like to: my form to appear with the checkboxes.

Comment: `echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="dtest" value="'. htmlspecialchars($row['row1']).'">'. htmlspecialchars($row['row1']).'</td>';`  **Note:** *This will not solve your other problems*